# org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Unsupported query: Merge Into

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql, apache-hudi

I am working on a Flink streaming job where I need to upsert data in the Hudi table. I am using merge into a query to upsert data in the Hudi table.

```
    Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(KafkaStreamTableDataStreamStream);
    tableEnv.createTemporaryView("table1", table);

    tableEnv.executeSql("Merge into target " +
            "USING table1 s0 " +
            "ON target.id = s0.id " +
            "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET amount=s0.amount");
```

This query is working fine in spark-shell. `But it is giving me Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Unsupported query: Merge into` .. in flink

Do merge into statement query work in the Flink job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink doesn't support MERGE statements. This has been brought up for [discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread/7wmfg3fzkb8w3w4pdv9073j4m2vjrj2p) but nothing has happened since then.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to go with the spark or another solution